# querySelectorAll doesnt work same getElByTagName

Tags: javascript

can you please tell me why querySelectorAll() doesn't work for me?

here is my code ,  UPDATE ON BOTTOM!

```
// html
<div class="features"></div>

// script with defer attr.
<script defer> 
const out = document.querySelector('.features')

    const features = [
      { title: 'Basic Operations' },
      { title: 'Functions' },
      { title: 'Looping' },
      { title: 'Arrays' },
      { title: 'Objects' },
      { title: 'Coookies' },
      { title: 'Ajax' },
    ]


 for(let i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
   const p = document.createElement('p')
   p.textContent = features[i].title
   p.className = 'text-center p'
   out.appendChild(p)
 }

 // all good until here !!!
 const p = document.querySelectorAll(".p");  // here my querySelectorAll() ignore me

mode.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault()

     if(e.target.classList.contains('bi-moon-stars-fill')) {
      p.style.color = 'lightgray' // console.log() error
     // TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')
     } else {
      p.style.color = 'black'
     }
   })

   
UPDATE:
 // I fix it with this code
mode.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault()

     if(e.target.classList.contains('bi-moon-stars-fill')) {
      for(let i = 0; i < p.length;i++) {
      p[i].style.color = 'lightgray'
     }
     } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
       p[i].style.color = 'black'
     }
     }
   })
```

I was trying to grab p tag by className , or by tagName but nothing happened.
Can you please tell me and show me how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the differences between [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)? If the latter returns something different how does that affect code like `p.style.color`?

Comment: I didn't see this answer on Stack overflow. Thanks, I fix it.